# Ошибка C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие";" перед "{"

Tags: c

Не могу найти ошибку.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <conio.h> \\ для функции getch()
#include <stdio.h> \\ для функций printf(), getchar(), putchar()
#define eof (-1)   \\ признак конца файла <Ctrl>+<z>

int main()
{
    int c;
    printf("make input>n");
    c = getchar();
    while (c != eof) {
        \\ error C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие";" перед "{"
        putchar(c);
        c = getchar();
    }
    getch(); /* вводит символ, но без эхо-сопровождения 
                (для организации задержки экрана) */
}
```

Comment: @Viktorwot, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: а зачем в дефайне eof нужны скобки ?

кроме того можно написать так: `while (eof != (c = getchar() ) ) {...}`

Comment: @Viktorwot, а чем общепринятый (и уже определенный в `<stdio.h>`) `EOF` не понравился?

Answer (score 3):

А я всегда думал что строковый комментарий это // а не \\

вот они из вашего дефайна и ползут в код

Comment: Спасибо от Души. Стыдно за рассеянность.